# Abstract algebra problem practice

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, book-recommendation

I'm currently studying abstract algebra,rings and fields specifically(entry level stuff,homomorphisms,ideals,quotients,cyclic groups to name most of them)

I am looking for a book focused around solved problems,to practice.Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please use the search feature first next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [*Schaum's Outline on Theory & Problems of Abstract Algebra*](https://archive.org/stream/SchaumsTheoryProblemsOfAbstractAlgebra/Fang-AbstractAlgebra#page/n5/mode/2up) written by Joong Fang?

It contains nearly 800 solved problems.  You may focus on parts IV (rings) and V (fields) of the book.

Comment: You,sir,are a hero and I genuinely love you

Comment: If you want a newer book, you may try [*Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications*](http://abstract.ups.edu/download/aata-20150812.pdf) written by Thomas W. Judson.  However, this book has solution/hints for *selected* problems.